# dynamic object key complaint from typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Edited:

How we can let it know the type if there have two cases value will be use for the `details` in `getDetails` fn?

We can't hardcoded the key inside the object, the `<Child />` may receive another value cases.

The type will passing from the parent to the child.

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Child details={["age", "location", "country"]} />
      <Child details={["gender", "height", "weight"]} />
    </>
  )
}

type DetailsOne = "age" | "location" | "country"
type DetailsTwo = "gender" | "height" | "weight"

type Details = DetailsOne | DetailsTwo


// Not working if set two cases for type
interface ChildProps {
  details: // -----> two cases value
     ["age", "location", "country"] | 
     ["gender", "height", "weight"]
}


// it work
interface ChildProps {
  details: ["age", "location", "country"]
}


const Child = ({details}: ChildProps) => {
  
 const getDetails = () => {
   const values: Record<Details, string> = {
     // only need those 3 passing from parent
     [details[0]]: "someValue", -----> typescript complaint
     [details[1]]: "someValue", -----> typescript complaint
     [details[2]]: "someValue"  -----> typescript complaint
   }

  const values: Record<Details, string> = {
     // this is not expected. just needed three key from the parent
     "age": "someValue", -----> typescript good
     "location": "someValue", -----> typescript good
     "country": "someValue",  -----> typescript good
     "gender": "someValue",   -----> typescript good
     "height": "someValue",  -----> typescript good
     "weight": "someValue"  -----> typescript good
   }
 }
 
  return ()
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What "TypeScript complaint" are you getting?

Comment: Updated the post issue.

Answer (score 0):

This look like work perfectly.

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Child details={["age", "location", "country"]} />
      <Child details={["gender", "height", "weight"]} />
    </>
  )
}

type DetailsOne = "age" | "location" | "country"
type DetailsTwo = "gender" | "height" | "weight"

type Details = DetailsOne | DetailsTwo


const Child = ({details}: ChildProps) => {
  
 const getDetails = () => {
   const values: Record<Details[number], string> = { // --> added [number]
     [details[0]]: "someValue", 
     [details[1]]: "someValue", 
     [details[2]]: "someValue" 
   }
 }
 
  return ()
}
```